# Iterate a Json object and add data to a tooltip with D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, iteration

I'm trying to do a little bit of data visualization and I'm struggling to display datas in a tooltip.

I want to display a map with cities on it and display data for each of these cities with a tooltip (on mouse over).

Here is one of my Json files (cities.json) :

```
[
  {
    "City": "Paris",
    "Longitude": 2.3488,
    "Lattitude": 48.85341,
    "Techno": {
      "Java": 5,
      "SQL": 5,
      "Javascript": 5,
    }
  },
  {
    "City": "Marseille",
    "Longitude": 5.38107,
    "Lattitude": 43.29695,
    "Techno": {
      "SQL": 9,
      "C": 7,
      "PHP": 7,
    }
  }
]
```

I'm able to display the cities on the map and a blanked tooltip.

I would like that for each hover of the mouse on a city, the tooltip displays all the data of the "Techno" object for the city.

For instance, a mouse over on Paris : the tooltip appears and displays "Technologies : SQL = 5% , C = 5% , PHP = 5%"

Here is my Js file:

```
const svg = d3.select("#map");
//...etc

// load data
var franceMap = d3.json("static/departments.json");
var cities = d3.json("static/cities.json");

// Append a DIV for the tooltip
var div = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

Promise.all([franceMap, cities]).then(function (values) {
  svg.selectAll("path").data(values[0].features).enter()
  //...etc

  // draw points
  svg.selectAll("circle").data(values[1]).enter().append("circle")
    //...etc
    
  // add labels and config the tooltip
  svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(values[1])
      .enter()
      //...etc

      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        div.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.9);
        div.html("Technologies : ") // Here is the code I'm looking for  
    // I want to iterate on the "Techno" object of the json file and add all 
    //its keys and values to the tooltip 
    
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX + 30 + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 30 + "px")
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        //...etc
      });
});
```

Thanks for any help !